# C# character encoding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

A message returns from my controls and I print it on the page. But the problem of character arises in the message. Using @Html.Raw solved my problem, but I read that it is not safe.

Controller :

```
else
{
    TempData["FailureMessage"] = "Geçersiz veri girişi. Lütfen tüm alanları doldurun.";
}

return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
```

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    try
    {
        if (TempData["FailureMessage"] != null)
        {
            ViewBag.FailureMessage= TempData["FailureMessage"];
        }
    }
}
```

Razor :

```
var failureMessage = ViewBag.FailureMessage as string;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(failureMessage))
{
    <script>
        Swal.fire({
                title: 'Başarısız!',
                text: '@failureMessage ',
                icon: 'success',
                timer: 5000,
                showConfirmButton: false,
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what the problem are you going to solve?